# How to take a filename from the text in the TextBox1

Tags: vb.net

I had a problem in setup a filename for the file that I was going to save as. I want to make it automatically take from the text in `TextBox1` and then make it as the filename of the file that I was going to save. Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim pdfFilename As String = "hahaha.pdf"
doc.Save(pdfFilename)
Process.Start(pdfFilename)
```

What do I need to modify from the above coding?

Comment: What happens when it runs?

Comment: I dont see any thing referring to TextBox1, in your code by default the working folder in a desktop application is YouAppFolder\bin\Debug so if no path is specified, it will save at bin\Debug folder

Comment: This site is not here to teach you the fundamentals of programming.  Go and read a beginners tutorial.  Getting the contents of a `TextBox` is about as basic as it gets.

Comment: owhh .. i just set the filename as "hahaha.pdf" , thanks guys for the suggestion, the problem is now solved. 

i just use this.

Comment: Im sorry for my weaknesses I will look forward to learn more about this, thanks in advance for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim pdfFilename As String = "I:\eQA\" & TextBox1.Text & ".pdf"
doc.Save(pdfFilename)
Process.Start(pdfFilename)
```

Comment: Good practice would be to set this text in a config file, which you could update anytime without having to rebuild your application.